# pycryptodome issue when trying to install in fedora

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-ec2

I am noticing the following error below whenever I try to install a package via pip via an AWS EC2 instance. I have tried many ways from stackoverflow and github issues.

System OS - Fedora

```
Running setup.py install for pycryptodome ... error
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
 command: /home/ec2-user/myenv/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-5u7yep04/pycryptodome/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-5u7yep04/pycryptodome/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-04kymlq7/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/ec2-user/myenv/include/site/python3.7/pycryptodome
     cwd: /tmp/pip-install-5u7yep04/pycryptodome/
Complete output (230 lines):
running install
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto
copying lib/Crypto/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto
copying lib/Crypto/pct_warnings.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/Cipher
copying lib/Crypto/Cipher/_mode_ccm.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/Cipher
copying lib/Crypto/Cipher/Blowfish.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/Cipher
copying lib/Crypto/Cipher/PKCS1_OAEP.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/Cipher
copying lib/Crypto/Cipher/PKCS1_v1_5.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/Cipher
copying lib/Crypto/Cipher/AES.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/Cipher
copying lib/Crypto/Cipher/CAST.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/Cipher
copying lib/Crypto/Cipher/DES3.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/Cipher
copying lib/Crypto/Cipher/_mode_openpgp.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/Cipher
copying lib/Crypto/Cipher/DES.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/Cipher
copying lib/Crypto/Cipher/_mode_eax.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/Cipher
copying lib/Crypto/Cipher/Salsa20.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/Cipher
copying lib/Crypto/Cipher/_mode_gcm.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/Cipher
copying lib/Crypto/Cipher/ARC2.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/Cipher
copying lib/Crypto/Cipher/_mode_ofb.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/Cipher
copying lib/Crypto/Cipher/_mode_cbc.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/Cipher
copying lib/Crypto/Cipher/_mode_cfb.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/Cipher
copying lib/Crypto/Cipher/_mode_siv.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/Cipher
copying lib/Crypto/Cipher/_mode_ecb.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/Cipher
copying lib/Crypto/Cipher/ChaCha20.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/Cipher
copying lib/Crypto/Cipher/ARC4.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/Cipher
copying lib/Crypto/Cipher/_mode_ctr.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/Cipher
copying lib/Crypto/Cipher/_mode_ocb.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/Cipher
copying lib/Crypto/Cipher/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/Cipher
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/Hash
copying lib/Crypto/Hash/CMAC.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/Hash
copying lib/Crypto/Hash/SHA512.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/Hash
copying lib/Crypto/Hash/SHA3_256.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/Hash
copying lib/Crypto/Hash/SHA1.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/Hash
copying lib/Crypto/Hash/MD4.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/Hash
copying lib/Crypto/Hash/RIPEMD.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/Hash
copying lib/Crypto/Hash/BLAKE2s.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/Hash
copying lib/Crypto/Hash/keccak.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/Hash
copying lib/Crypto/Hash/SHA3_384.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/Hash
copying lib/Crypto/Hash/HMAC.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/Hash
copying lib/Crypto/Hash/BLAKE2b.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/Hash
copying lib/Crypto/Hash/SHA.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/Hash
copying lib/Crypto/Hash/SHAKE256.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/Hash
copying lib/Crypto/Hash/SHA3_512.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/Hash
copying lib/Crypto/Hash/SHA256.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/Hash
copying lib/Crypto/Hash/RIPEMD160.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/Hash
copying lib/Crypto/Hash/SHAKE128.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/Hash
copying lib/Crypto/Hash/MD2.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/Hash
copying lib/Crypto/Hash/MD5.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/Hash
copying lib/Crypto/Hash/SHA224.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/Hash
copying lib/Crypto/Hash/SHA384.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/Hash
copying lib/Crypto/Hash/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/Hash
copying lib/Crypto/Hash/SHA3_224.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/Hash
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/IO
copying lib/Crypto/IO/PKCS8.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/IO
copying lib/Crypto/IO/_PBES.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/IO
copying lib/Crypto/IO/PEM.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/IO
copying lib/Crypto/IO/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/IO
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/PublicKey
copying lib/Crypto/PublicKey/DSA.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/PublicKey
copying lib/Crypto/PublicKey/ElGamal.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/PublicKey
copying lib/Crypto/PublicKey/RSA.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/PublicKey
copying lib/Crypto/PublicKey/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/PublicKey
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/Protocol
copying lib/Crypto/Protocol/SecretSharing.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/Protocol
copying lib/Crypto/Protocol/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/Protocol
copying lib/Crypto/Protocol/KDF.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/Protocol
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/Random
copying lib/Crypto/Random/random.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/Random
copying lib/Crypto/Random/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/Random
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/Signature
copying lib/Crypto/Signature/PKCS1_PSS.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/Signature
copying lib/Crypto/Signature/DSS.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/Signature
copying lib/Crypto/Signature/pss.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/Signature
copying lib/Crypto/Signature/PKCS1_v1_5.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/Signature
copying lib/Crypto/Signature/pkcs1_15.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/Signature
copying lib/Crypto/Signature/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/Signature
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/Util
copying lib/Crypto/Util/Counter.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/Util
copying lib/Crypto/Util/asn1.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/Util
copying lib/Crypto/Util/py3compat.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/Util
copying lib/Crypto/Util/Padding.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/Util
copying lib/Crypto/Util/_number_new.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/Util
copying lib/Crypto/Util/_raw_api.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/Util
copying lib/Crypto/Util/strxor.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/Util
copying lib/Crypto/Util/number.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/Util
copying lib/Crypto/Util/RFC1751.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/Util
copying lib/Crypto/Util/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/Util
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/Math
copying lib/Crypto/Math/Numbers.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/Math
copying lib/Crypto/Math/_Numbers_gmp.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/Math
copying lib/Crypto/Math/_Numbers_int.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/Math
copying lib/Crypto/Math/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/Math
copying lib/Crypto/Math/Primality.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/Math
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/SelfTest
copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/st_common.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/SelfTest
copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/__main__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/SelfTest
copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/SelfTest
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Cipher
copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Cipher/test_AES.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Cipher
copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Cipher/test_CAST.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Cipher
copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Cipher/common.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Cipher
copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Cipher/test_DES3.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Cipher
copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Cipher/test_OCB.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Cipher
copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Cipher/test_pkcs1_oaep.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Cipher
copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Cipher/test_Salsa20.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Cipher
copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Cipher/test_Blowfish.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Cipher
copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Cipher/test_ARC2.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Cipher
copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Cipher/test_pkcs1_15.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Cipher
copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Cipher/test_DES.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Cipher
copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Cipher/test_ARC4.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Cipher
copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Cipher/test_ChaCha20.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Cipher
copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Cipher/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Cipher
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash
copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash/test_BLAKE2.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash
copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash/test_SHA3_512.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash
copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash/test_CMAC.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash
copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash/common.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash
copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash/test_SHA1.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash
copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash/test_MD5.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash
copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash/test_HMAC.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash
copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash/test_SHA256.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash
copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash/test_SHA3_224.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash
copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash/test_SHA224.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash
copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash/loader.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash
copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash/test_SHA3_384.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash
copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash/test_SHA384.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash
copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash/test_SHAKE.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash
copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash/test_MD4.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash
copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash/test_MD2.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash
copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash/test_keccak.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash
copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash/test_RIPEMD160.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash
copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash/test_SHA3_256.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash
copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash/test_SHA512.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash
copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/SelfTest/IO
copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/IO/test_PKCS8.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/SelfTest/IO
copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/IO/test_PBES.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/SelfTest/IO
copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/IO/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/SelfTest/IO
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Protocol
copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Protocol/test_KDF.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Protocol
copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Protocol/test_rfc1751.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Protocol
copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Protocol/test_SecretSharing.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Protocol
copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Protocol/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Protocol
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/SelfTest/PublicKey
copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/PublicKey/test_import_DSA.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/SelfTest/PublicKey
copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/PublicKey/test_ElGamal.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/SelfTest/PublicKey
copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/PublicKey/test_import_RSA.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/SelfTest/PublicKey
copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/PublicKey/test_DSA.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/SelfTest/PublicKey
copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/PublicKey/test_RSA.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/SelfTest/PublicKey
copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/PublicKey/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/SelfTest/PublicKey
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Random
copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Random/test_random.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Random
copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Random/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Random
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Signature
copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Signature/nist.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Signature
copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Signature/test_pkcs1_15.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Signature
copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Signature/test_dss.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Signature
copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Signature/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Signature
copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Signature/test_pss.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Signature
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Util
copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Util/test_number.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Util
copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Util/test_strxor.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Util
copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Util/test_asn1.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Util
copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Util/test_Padding.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Util
copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Util/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Util
copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Util/test_Counter.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Util
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Math
copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Math/test_Numbers.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Math
copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Math/test_Primality.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Math
copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Math/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Math
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash/test_vectors
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash/test_vectors/SHA3
copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash/test_vectors/SHA3/ShortMsgKAT_SHA3-224.txt -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash/test_vectors/SHA3
copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash/test_vectors/SHA3/ShortMsgKAT_SHAKE256.txt -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash/test_vectors/SHA3
copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash/test_vectors/SHA3/ShortMsgKAT_SHAKE128.txt -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash/test_vectors/SHA3
copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash/test_vectors/SHA3/ShortMsgKAT_SHA3-512.txt -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash/test_vectors/SHA3
copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash/test_vectors/SHA3/ShortMsgKAT_SHA3-256.txt -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash/test_vectors/SHA3
copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash/test_vectors/SHA3/ShortMsgKAT_SHA3-384.txt -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash/test_vectors/SHA3
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash/test_vectors/keccak
copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash/test_vectors/keccak/ShortMsgKAT_512.txt -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash/test_vectors/keccak
copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash/test_vectors/keccak/LongMsgKAT_384.txt -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash/test_vectors/keccak
copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash/test_vectors/keccak/readme.txt -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash/test_vectors/keccak
copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash/test_vectors/keccak/ExtremelyLongMsgKAT_384.txt -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash/test_vectors/keccak
copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash/test_vectors/keccak/LongMsgKAT_224.txt -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash/test_vectors/keccak
copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash/test_vectors/keccak/LongMsgKAT_256.txt -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash/test_vectors/keccak
copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash/test_vectors/keccak/ShortMsgKAT_256.txt -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash/test_vectors/keccak
copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash/test_vectors/keccak/ExtremelyLongMsgKAT_256.txt -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash/test_vectors/keccak
copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash/test_vectors/keccak/ExtremelyLongMsgKAT_512.txt -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash/test_vectors/keccak
copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash/test_vectors/keccak/ShortMsgKAT_384.txt -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash/test_vectors/keccak
copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash/test_vectors/keccak/LongMsgKAT_512.txt -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash/test_vectors/keccak
copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash/test_vectors/keccak/ExtremelyLongMsgKAT_224.txt -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash/test_vectors/keccak
copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash/test_vectors/keccak/ShortMsgKAT_224.txt -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash/test_vectors/keccak
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash/test_vectors/BLAKE2s
copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash/test_vectors/BLAKE2s/blake2s-test.txt -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash/test_vectors/BLAKE2s
copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash/test_vectors/BLAKE2s/tv2.txt -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash/test_vectors/BLAKE2s
copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash/test_vectors/BLAKE2s/tv1.txt -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash/test_vectors/BLAKE2s
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash/test_vectors/BLAKE2b
copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash/test_vectors/BLAKE2b/tv2.txt -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash/test_vectors/BLAKE2b
copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash/test_vectors/BLAKE2b/tv1.txt -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash/test_vectors/BLAKE2b
copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash/test_vectors/BLAKE2b/blake2b-test.txt -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Hash/test_vectors/BLAKE2b
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Signature/test_vectors
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Signature/test_vectors/DSA
copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Signature/test_vectors/DSA/FIPS_186_3_SigGen.txt -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Signature/test_vectors/DSA
copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Signature/test_vectors/DSA/FIPS_186_3_SigVer.rsp -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Signature/test_vectors/DSA
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Signature/test_vectors/PKCS1-v1.5
copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Signature/test_vectors/PKCS1-v1.5/SigVer15_186-3.rsp -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Signature/test_vectors/PKCS1-v1.5
copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Signature/test_vectors/PKCS1-v1.5/SigGen15_186-3.txt -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Signature/test_vectors/PKCS1-v1.5
copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Signature/test_vectors/PKCS1-v1.5/SigGen15_186-2.txt -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Signature/test_vectors/PKCS1-v1.5
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Signature/test_vectors/PKCS1-PSS
copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Signature/test_vectors/PKCS1-PSS/SigGenPSS_186-2.txt -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Signature/test_vectors/PKCS1-PSS
copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Signature/test_vectors/PKCS1-PSS/SigGenPSS_186-3.txt -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Signature/test_vectors/PKCS1-PSS
copying lib/Crypto/SelfTest/Signature/test_vectors/PKCS1-PSS/SigVerPSS_186-3.rsp -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/SelfTest/Signature/test_vectors/PKCS1-PSS
Skipping optional fixer: buffer
Skipping optional fixer: idioms
Skipping optional fixer: set_literal
Skipping optional fixer: ws_comma
running build_ext
Compiling support for Intel AES instructions
building 'Crypto.Hash._MD2' extension
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src
gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -DLTC_NO_ASM -DHAVE_CPUID_H -Isrc/ -I/home/ec2-user/myenv/include -I/usr/include/python3.7m -c src/MD2.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/MD2.o
gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-z,relro -g build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/MD2.o -L/usr/lib64 -lpython3.7m -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/Crypto/Hash/_MD2.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpython3.7m
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
----------------------------------------
```

Rolling back uninstall of pycryptodome
  Moving to /home/ec2-user/myenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/Crypto/
   from /home/ec2-user/myenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/~rypto
  Moving to /home/ec2-user/myenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pycryptodome-3.9.7.dist-info/
   from /home/ec2-user/myenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/~ycryptodome-3.9.7.dist-info
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /home/ec2-user/myenv/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-5u7yep04/pycryptodome/setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-5u7yep04/pycryptodome/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-04kymlq7/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/ec2-user/myenv/include/site/python3.7/pycryptodome Check the logs for full command output.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else facing similar issues, I managed to fix this issue by installing the required dependencies > sudo yum install gcc gmp python3-devel